# Passing data from PHP back to HTML with AJAX used

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Currently, I am writing a login form that allows user to login. After they have login successfully, the username of of the user will be displayed in the HTML. However, I have no idea how to do it.

**PHP**

```
$username = $Row['username'];
mysqli_free_result($Result);
mysqli_close($Link);
echo json_encode(array('success'=>'true','action'=>'login',  'username'=>$username, 'console.log'=>$Query));
```

**AJAX**

```
success: function(data) {
console.log('controller sent data to the model');
console.log(data);
//data from JSON Array
if (data.action === "login") {
    window.location = https://n3228691.scm.tees.ac.uk/Yii/MACC/dashboard.html"; }
```

**Dashboard.html**

(I have no idea how to edit this webpage)

Cheers for your kindly help.

Comment: $('#result_div').html(data.username);

Comment: @Arno, you mean putting this code into my dashboard.html?

Comment: This is just example code, dont copy/paste it directly. If you add functionality like this in your success callback you can edit an element and show the username.

Comment: @Arno sorry I am not sure if I can understand your meaning, since I am a beginner using PHP, Ajax

Comment: See this jsfiddle as en example: https://jsfiddle.net/m22u9xfv/